# How to check if a stored procedure exist?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have searched the net and I've found a [post](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.databases.oracle.server/2005-07/msg00386.html) that uses the following snippet to check if a stored procedure exists:

```
select * 
  from USER_SOURCE 
 where type='PROCEDURE' 
   and name='my_stored_procedure.'
```

Is there any other way to check if a procedure exists?

**Edited to add:**

Before posting SQL Server ways, please I'm looking for ORACLE ways.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Alternatives:

**USER_PROCEDURES:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_PROCEDURES
 WHERE object_name = 'MY_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

**USER_OBJECTS:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_OBJECTS
 WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
   AND object_name = 'MY_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

Comment: +1.. the other views to remember: `ALL_OBJECTS`, `DBA_OBJECTS` (if you have that priv). Same for `_PROCEDURES` too.

Comment: If you have an invalid procedure (due to compiling errors), the invalid procedure is listet in `USER_OBJECTS` and `ALL_OBJECTS` but not listed in `USER_PROCEDURES` and `ALL_PROCEDURES`.

Comment: what if stored procedure is inside package?

Comment: this only shows YOUR procs/objects, not all

Answer (score 7):

Something that worked for me!

```
SELECT text
FROM all_source
WHERE name = 'MY_SP_NAME'
ORDER BY line;
```

Alternatively you can try calling SP like this:

```
CALL MY_SP_NAME();
```

You might end up error like this, but that confirms you have SP defined there:

```
OCI Statement Execution failure.ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MY_SP_NAME'
```

Comment: This only shows objects where you have privileges on, not ALL

Answer (score 3):

The only way to see if a procedure exists in the database is though querying `DBA_OBJECTS`. The disadvantage here is that only a dba has access to this view. Second best is using all_objects. `ALL_OBJECTS` shows you the objects for which you have somehow a privilege. `USER_OBJECTS` only shows you your own objects.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the query below in SQL*PLUS, ODBC Test,...

SELECT text FROM all_source WHERE name='MY_PROCEDURE' ORDER BY line

where MY_PROCEDURE is the stored procedure name.

Below is sample output:

Get Data All:
"TEXT"
"PROCEDURE Usp_Get_Blob
"(
"P_DOC_ID INT,
"P_DOC_TEXT OUT BLOB)
"as
"begin
"  select B1 
  into p_doc_text
"  from blobtest
"  where ID = p_doc_id;
"end; "

Comment: This only shows objects where you have privileges on, not ALL

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find stored procedure with any of the methods above.

Reason: stored procedure was inside package. Oracle uses packages to gather several stored procedures in one module.

Comment: that is not a stored procedure but a packaged one.

Answer (score 1):

This will display the stored procedure and its contents stored in the table.

```
select
   name c1,
   text c2
from
   dba_source
where
   name = upper('procedure_name')
order by
   line asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * 
  from USER_SOURCE 
 where type='PROCEDURE' 
   and name='my_stored_procedure.'

Comment: What is this?  The same thing as the question?