# drop procedure if exists in DB Oracle

Tags: oracle, procedure

Can someone tell me how I can drop a PROCEDURE in Oracle, but just if it exists ?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS XYZ;
```

The above does not work.

Comment: No, In Oracle, you don't have this feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is to eliminate error messages in a script, then you can try

```
begin
   execute immediate 'drop procedure xyz';
exception when others then
   if sqlcode != -4043 then
      raise;
   end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: "Exception when others then" is almost always a bug waiting to happen.  In this case, the idea is to drop procedure xyz, and mask the ORA-04043 error that would normally occur if the procedure you attempt to drop already doesn't exist.  That's fine, but what if procedure XYZ *does* exist, but the user attempting the drop doesn't have permission to drop it?  The drop would raise ORA-01031, but it would be ignored, due to the 'when others'.  Better to declare the exception you want to ignore, specifically, than to use 'others'.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

```
DECLARE
  V_NUM NUMBER;
BEGIN     
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   V_NUM
  FROM   USER_OBJECTS
  WHERE  OBJECT_NAME = 'XYZ'
  AND    OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'; 

  IF V_NUM > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE XYZ';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Dropped');
  END IF;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check dictionary view before:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_PROCEDURES WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: Notice that `PROCEDURE_NAME` will only work for procedures in packages, you should use `OBJECT_NAME` instead for all kind of functions

Comment: @EugeneK inside a package you cannot drop a procedure anyway

Comment: so are you saying that your answer will not help topic starter?

Answer (score 1):

A complete example:

```
declare
   c int;
begin
       select count(*) into c from user_procedures where object_type = 'FUNCTION' and object_name = 'ABC';
       if c = 1 then
          execute immediate 'DROP FUNCTION ABC';
       end if;
end;
```

Comment: If you have an invalid procedure (due to compiling errors), the invalid procedure is listet in `USER_OBJECTS` and `ALL_OBJECTS` but not listed in `USER_PROCEDURES` and `ALL_PROCEDURES`.
See also: [Question 5721474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721474/how-to-check-if-a-stored-procedure-exist)